# Change $(basename "$0") Output From Executed base64 Encode

Tags: shell-script

Inside script.sh

```
echo $(basename "$0")
```

Then I Encoded script.sh using base64:

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env bash' > other.sh  
echo "echo '$(base64 script.sh)' | base64 -d | sh" >> other.sh
```

Why doesn't it not displaying "script.sh" as `basename "$0"` when i run "other.sh"?
But instead it displays "sh"
How to make it display `script.sh`?

Comment: Just as a general point in script writing, whenever you have `echo $(command)` you're better off to say simply `command`.  So `script.sh` could be just: `basename "$0"`

Comment: @JimL. Can you give me an explain?

Comment: Try: `basename "/bin/sh"`  Now try: `echo "$(basename "/bin/sh")"`  Those commands do exactly the same thing, but the first one is better, and the second one is inefficient.

Comment: @JimL. It's not work